# Ubuntu 12.10 unity won't start on startup

Tags: unity, 12.10

I've just updated to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04, and now Unity won't automatically start on startup! I have to get around this problem every time I start my machine by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to get a pseudo-terminal, and starting Unity manually. How do I make Ubuntu 12.10 automatically start on startup? Also, is anyone else experience my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if ubuntu **unity plugin enabled** in `ccsm`

[image]

and see if this work

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwFG9XpdYEg

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can confirm that the ubuntu Unity Plugin is enabled, and the Youtube video didn't help because it's about restarting Unity. My problem is that Unity doesn't start in the first place. How do I make it automatically start on startup?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/unity-3d-launcher-top-panel-doesnt-load.html http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/ubuntu-unity-doesnt-start-907131/ here some links check it

Comment: or as temporary ..i would try to put command wich execute unity to startup application search start up in dash and add command to manually start unity (name it somehow)

Comment: Actually, the Youtube video did help. For some reason, on one of the start-ups, I opened a terminal and typed `$setsid unity`, shut it down, and restarted, and it now works. I have NO IDEA why. But thank you very much though, for this and all the other resources you've googled!

Comment: Also, sorry I can't vote you up, because I only have 1 reputation.

Comment: the only purpose of voting is that people find the answer and working suggestion .Glad its ok for you now

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I wish you knew exactly what you did, because it would be really helpful right about now...

Answer (score 4):

After login, Ctrl+Alt+T

```
cp .config/dconf/user .config/dconf/user.bkp
rm .config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config .config/dconf/user
```

Then Unity magically will appear.

Logout, login again and enjoy!

PS: some of your config will reset. We need to discover what config need to reset instead of remove .config/dconf/user.

EDIT:
To reset only compiz files:

1) After login, Ctrl+Alt+T

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
rm .config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config ; dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity
```

2) Logout and login

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/crontab` file and enter the `>@reboot root startx` command.

If this does not work, there are several other commands like `>startx`. I am also running it on a VM.