# Ubuntu 12.10. doesn't start after update

Tags: updates, startup

I just did the newest update from the Update manager, and now after restarting Ubuntu. It won't start anymore. I went to the login menu but when I logined Unity or Gnome, I could only see the desktop background and the mouse is moving but nothing else appears, no menus, nothing.

Comment: maybe you should give more information about this. Like does booting up to another OS. Or reinstalling, and restoring works.

Comment: I have Windows 7 installed on another partition that works fine. I have an i3 core and an integrated graphics card + an AMD card. The AMD card is disabled. I'm not sure but I think I have xorg graphic card drivers..

Comment: If you have been using the FGLRX/Catalyst driver you will need to reinstall the driver after upgrade

Comment: aren't these drivers only for amd graphic cards? since I disabled the AMD card via switcheroo, the integrated card should be running. but in any case, how would I install the drivers? I can't get Ubuntu to boot up and when I go to the recovery mode and want to set up a network connection, it hangs at fsck from util-linux.

Comment: okay, i can get into command mode with ctrl+alt+F1 and I installed ati drivers according to this guide: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200 but it still doesn't start up, just hangs at the desktop background screen after I log in (though the login screen looks different now after the ati drivers install)

Comment: i also uninstalled and reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-intel, but no luck.. could please someone guide me through this

Comment: If your Ctrl+Alt+T command works maybe it means the Unity is having problem to start. The solution below worked to me: http://askubuntu.com/a/244064/123806