# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity: Black screen with cursor only, when external display is connected before booting laptop

Tags: 12.04, unity, boot, display, lightdm

Whenever I connect an external display to the DSub port of my laptop **before** booting into Ubuntu, something goes wrong in Unity to cause the exact same problem as described here: [After logging in, there's a black screen and my cursor, nothing else! in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu) Rebooting without the display connected does not fix it.

A once-off fix is to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

or, much quicker, this:

```
unity --reset
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Side effect of this solution: I lose all of my Unity appearance settings.

My problem, however, is that I need to boot with the external display connected quite often. Who knows what goes wrong inside Unity and/or how to fix it permanently?

Comment: It might help to know what hardware you are using. Some laptops have a BIOS setting to enable/disable external.

Comment: I checked... No such settings in my BIOS. At least not with the current (factory) firmware. HP ProBook 6560b

Answer (score 1):

I've received this black screen with cursor myself (I use 4 monitors, and so unplugging them happens often).

However my fix was to correctly install my GPU's drivers.

Since your laptop [apparently](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-probook-6560b-15-6-core-i5-2410m-windows-7-pro-64-bit-4-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd-series/specs/) has an Intel HD 3000 series GPU have you tried installing up-to-date drivers? The *Additional Drivers* tab in your *Software & Updates* part of *System Settings* would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script to run at startup that uses your quickest workaround, I.E.

```
unity --reset
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This shouldn't have any negative consequences (other than the possible loss of any customized settings as mentioned in the question) if the external isn't connected and should resolve the problem if it is....

Source: Question

Comment: Side effect of this solution: I lose all of my Unity appearance settings when the script runs.

Comment: Added that missing information to your question.

Comment: It's very obvious from `man unity`:
    --reset
        This option allows the user to reset profile parameters in  compiz and restart the Unity shell with default settings.

Comment: This is true, but what's not obvious is that you changed your Unity appearance settings from the defaults. I felt that information was useful.

Comment: Have you tried simply `sudo service lightdm restart` ?

Comment: i tried these commends... and i lost my setting!...after 'unity --reset'........ i tried 'sudo service lightdm restart' too.... it says: Job for lightdm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status lightdm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
what should i do now?

Comment: @sina Are you still running Ubuntu 12.04? If so I would recommend  https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release if not you may wish to open a new question (linking to this one if you feel it provides background).

Comment: No I'm on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Then my latter suggestion would logically apply.