# Black screen with mouse cursor upon boot, Fixed by logging in

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, login-screen, bumblebee

Recently I had to reinstall my ubuntu 12.04 due to some kernel installation issues.
So i grabbed a new  livecd and installed it.
Went on to configure drivers and settings.
I have bumblebee installed to handle the Nvidia 620M for 3D applications and the Intel HD4000 cpu integrated chip to do desktop environment and such.

THe issue being is after bumblebee was installed i didn’t see the login in screen anymore.
But i heard the login screen sound so i typed in my password hit enter and voila it works.
I want to fix this though what i have found so far is.

In virtual console starting lightdm returns with Failed to use bus name org.freeDesktop.DisplayManager do you have the appropriate permissions ?

I've looked around and cant find a solution similar problem i've seen like this was just unity to starting at all mine starts but only after logging in .

If I need to supply additional info please tell me so and I will do so.

Another discovery/insight. Turning on ALPM https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementALPM cause's the screen to be black on launch as well as the device isn’t properly called. Also has weird side effect on the wifi.

So i have it "FIXED" What i did is was a 12 hour wild goose chase around ubuntu ^^ In all seriousness I reinstalled to make sure it a a reproduce-able issue. After confirming it was I went into /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia and added my PCI BusID of my video card. This was to make bumblebee work. After I done this I had the same issue again. After some research I changed line 15 in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf TurnCardOffAtExit=false into TurnCardOffAtExit=true.

Now everything works as far as I can tell have to do some more testing. Another issue i have now even before bumblebee is that loging in takes ages(20+ sec). Would be nice if someone has an idea what that does.

EDIT: This does bring up the question that 620M doesn’t work out of the box (Meh it's linux nothing does) but if you follow https://askubuntu.com/a/36936/229978 There is no mention of it.

EDIT 2: still broken open for any suggestions

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post a self-answer and then mark it as answer as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, [and correct me if I'm wrong] your problem is stated in the title and is Unity-related. Can you try:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

You can also try going to Synaptic Package Manager and "Mark for Reinstallation" only **after** you've done the above.

If I'm wrong, though, please clarify what exactly you're trying to fix/do.

Comment: Will try right now. Just got a new lead getting out of hibernation it returns this pci device is not a vga device. I'll let you know where I end up.

Comment: This is what i found when doing $ sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging.
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: unity-team staging
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: unity-team staging. Thank you so far for you help.

Comment: Hmm, have you done the general update via SU or terminal? Are you still having this issue?

Comment: I did apt-get update multiple times and tan the update manager multiple times. still having it even after my latest post. I don't know what to do I think I've tried everything I know. I know12.04 LTS has an update that supposedly fixes this. don't know if I have it.

Comment: Sorry for such late delays. By any chance, do you have NVIDIA card?

Comment: yeah 620m with bumblebee running and the 304 driver

Comment: Okay, I found this: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*

Comment: It's not 100% the same as your problem, but: http://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu

Comment: I already went through the entire thread trying everything in there including uninstalling bumblebees and all nvidia packages. what I think is has happend is that a nvidia package messed with the mesa driver for the Intel 4000hd. since my desktop runs on  the integrated graphics. anyway to check this ?