# Black screen after boot in Ubuntu 15.04 (x86_64), Intel HD5500 (i915 driver) (reposted)

Tags: grub2, graphics, 15.04, i915

I know this question has been asked so many times (since 2011 from what I found out), but none of the responses seem to resolve the issue in my laptop, so apologies for the repetition.

I tried appending "nomodeset" to the grub boot and it no only doesn't work, but also it disables hardware acceleration, rendering X11 unusable.

I also tried some other configurations ("vga=773", like the different "video:"), but nothing seems to work.

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

I installed packages grub2-splashimages and grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate, assuming it could be that just there was nothing configured, but nothing makes any difference.

Booting on text by adding "set gfxpayload=text" works, and it shows the textual booting process. But I didn't get anything useful from that ... (but that it takes a minute to start the cryptswap thing, the longest part of the boot process apparently)

I didn't see anything in dmesg that stand out, but then I wouldn't know what to look for.

Also I get random blanking of the screen during normal work: the computer is still working (even sound works), but some times the screen suddenly goes black while I'm typing. I recover from that by pressing the power button (going to suspend mode) and then coming back. I've seen reports of this also elsewhere, but it is a different graphics card.

Any ideas ? Many many thanks in advance for any help!

ps: let me know if any other information I can post here would help

Some references I looked and tried already:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

After trying the answer to the apparently duplicated question:

[After logging in, there's a black screen and my cursor, nothing else! in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu)

It seemed to have worked for a week, but I think it was only a coincidence, it's now randomly happening again. I've tried repeating the same commands and it doesn't have an effect.

It even happened once in the session manager, while i was typing my password to log in.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance!

Reposted since original question was marked as answered/duplicated and I didn't find a way to reopen it.

Comment: It may be a hardware issue, perhaps with the video connection. I am experiencing the exact same symptoms on HDMI. As a last effort I entered the Intel Visual BIOS menu and even that screen displayed the same issue. I haven't had the opportunity to replace the cable yet, however, so it's still just a theory.