# Desktop under Ubuntu server 14.04.2 doesn't work

Tags: server, .desktop

I've already installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 After it I've executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After reboot, I can login with my user and password and ubuntu desktop appears without any buttons. There is nothing I can do, only move cursor, no icons, no options to select

Comment: possible duplicate of [After logging in, there's a black screen and my cursor, nothing else! in Ubuntu 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It's not the same behavour, neither the same version. The problem is different and the solution not good for my problem

Comment: [edit] to explain why then

Comment: For who has the same problem than me, the solution was removing nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0):

Answered [in Comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641214/desktop-under-ubuntu-server-14-04-2-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment920915_641214) by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/419845/mblascog):

> For who has the same problem than me, the solution was removing nvidia drivers