# Icons all missing - blank desktop

Tags: unity, icons

15.04 - Unity -

This morning, all my icons, as well as the top bar, went missing.

I've tried everything I've found here (commands for re-installing unity, etc) but nothing has helped.

I HAVE noticed that the GUEST profile works just fine. Everything displays great. So this would SEEM to indicate a problem with the configuration of my primary account, right?

Is there a way to locate and reset my main accounts Unity configuration using the Guest account? If not, I CAN log into my main account, and use CTRL-ALT-F1 to get to a login screen, where I can log in as my main account.

To be clear, the only thing that appears when I log in as my main user is the desktop background, and the mouse cursor. Nothing else.

This seems to be a common problem, but none of the fixes out there are working so far.

The system is an old HP Mini netbook. No fancy GPUs.

Help!

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Ravan -- that worked! Thankfully, the UI was still together enough that I was able to save the script for "unity-reset" to a USB drive and install then run it in terminal. It looks like maybe going forward, that functionality should be added back into new versions of the OS. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (thanks to link from Ravan) in case anyone else, like myself, has this bug and bangs their head into it.

Upon login to Unity, (Ubuntu 15.04) icons, top status bar, everything but the cursor vanish. On my system, the Guest login worked just fine. I only have my main login and GUEST on my system.

System is a very old HP Mini netbook with generic Intel GPU.

Suspect my user's Unity config got borked somehow. No recent installs or modifications on my part; I use the system for work.

Fix: using another system and a USB key, downloaded the Unity reset tool from first link here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html

Plugged the USB key into the problem laptop while logged in as my essentially useless main profile.

Was able to install the DEB package using software center, which thankfully came up.

The big bonus I didn't notice at first - RIGHT-CLICK menu still works, so right-click and open Terminal that way, then issue the "unity-reset" command.

After a few moments, everything popped up. Config was reset, naturally, so the icons were HUGE. Also, the icons of installed programs were all missing, so I had to manually add things like Evolution Mail back to the launcher bar.

-Fin